# how to set the background-size to 100% using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

When i using the nivo-lazy slider,a problem arises that images is not fit on the slider-wrapper. On nivo slider i found a solution that

```
.nivoSlider img {
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
max-width: none;

    width:100%;
    height:100% !important;
}
```

But it not working on nivo-lazy slider.

I think that nivo-lazy slider works by changing background-image using jquery. When I put background-size:100% 100%; in element-style on browser's inspect element; It will works. So I need to set background-size to 100% through Jquery.

How can I do this?? Thanks for help in advance.

**Update**

I write in the following format.

```
slider.css('background','url("something.jpeg") no-repeat','background-size','100% 100%');
```

in jquery-nivo-slider.js at line 123.

Then I will change the code to

```
slider.css('background','url("'+ parse_src(vars.currentImage) +'") no-repeat'); 
document.getElementById('slider').style.backgroundSize = "100% 100%";
```

But now the problem is that I using dynamic size of images and that slider will set small small divs and its width according to each image width propertionly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change any CSS properties using jQuery.

If the element you are using has `id="nivo-lazy-div`, then do this:

```
$("#nivo-lazy-div").css("background-size":"100% 100%");
```

**Update**

If you are only changing the background image, then you don't actually need to set this every time. Just add it to your CSS and any background image will be re-sized.

```
#nivo-lazy-div{
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

**Update**

Do this:

```
slider.css({
    'background' : 'url("' + parse_src(vars.currentImage) + '") no-repeat',
    'background-size' : '100% 100%',
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help  your comment is right .But in my case it will not working.I write in the following format.  slider.css('background','url("something.jpeg") no-repeat','background-size','100% 100%');  in jquery-nivo-slider.js at line 123 .  Then I will change the code to    slider.css('background','url("'+ parse_src(vars.currentImage) +'") no-repeat');
        document.getElementById('slider').style.backgroundSize = "100% 100%";   .  But now the problem is that I using dynamic size of images and that slider will set small small divs and its width according  to each image width propertionly

Comment: @manuthalasseril Ok, copy paste your generated HTML code in your question.

Comment: @manuthalasseril Are you saying the size of the `div` is changing according to the image?

Comment: each images are different width and different height . I cant set a fixed height and width for images. My test page is uploaded and here is the [link](http://dotsolutionssa.com/test.html)

Comment: I also try with your  updated answer .but it will not  works .thanks for the reply.   I have  a link  to my page please check it [link](http://dotsolutionssa.com/test.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to set your background 100% just after your document loaded.
better use id for your img tag, as for example.

```
<img id="image" src="your_image.jpg">
```

Use below written code..

`<script>$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#image').css("width":"100%","height":"100%"); 
}); </script>`

don't forget to add jQuery library.

or you can simple use ..

```
<img src="your_image.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" >
```

I hope it will work.

Comment: thanks for your help. But in my case it cannot be used. I have using the nivo-lazy slider. It will take the source of each image tag and set that image source to a div's background.